# How to create SQL Stored Procedure with parameters of type List<string>

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, parameter

I need to create a Stored Procedure that will take parameters of type List. For example :

```
Select *
 From Table
Where State   in @StateList
   or Lob     in @LobList
   or Company in @CompanyList
```

The parameters @StateList, @LobList and @CompanyList will contain string data like :

```
StateList:[ "GA", "AL", "TN" ]
LobList:[ "D20", "PXL", "APM" ]
CompanyList:[ "QQ", "WW", "RE" ]
```

Does SQL allow this ?

Comment: Which platform are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2012

Comment: the parameters will be passed into the Stored Procedure thru an API written in C#.

Comment: Yeah, you can't really do that. You'd wanna use [table valued parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters) instead.

Comment: ok, thank you for the info. first I've heard of that term. I'll take a look. thanks again.

Comment: You technically could if you append the string to a query string and then exec the whole thing.  It's messy and doesn't get the benefits of precompiling though.

Comment: @Jason, see [the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters) for examples of TVPs. You can pass an 'IEnumerable<T>' as the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no type you can use with SQL Server that would let you pass in and use a list as you've suggested.

You have two options:

### Dynamic SQL

Pass the list in as a string value (`'(12, 34, 13, 29)'`). Build a `nvarchar` string with your SQL statement, with that value concatenated in:

```
SET @stmt = N'Select *
  From Table
 Where State   in ' + @StateList + N'
    or Lob     in ' + @LobList + N'
    or Company in ' + @CompanyList
```

Then, `EXECUTE sp_executesql @stmt` to run the dynamic SQL.

### Use table-valued parameters

SQL Server does allow table variables to be passed, as [table-valued parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters). You can pass an 'IEnumerable' as the value in your C# code (see the docs at the link for more data). Obviously, you'd need to re-write your query:

```
SELECT *
  FROM Table tbl
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @StateTbl where State = tbl.State)
    OR EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @LobTbl where Lob = tbl.Lob)
    OR EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @CompanyTbl where Company = tbl.Company)
;
```

or

```
SELECT tbl.*
  FROM Table tbl
         LEFT JOIN @StateTbl st ON (tbl.State = st.State)
         LEFT JOIN @LobTbl lob ON (tbl.Lob = lob.Lob)
         LEFT JOIN @CompanyTbl co ON (tbl.Company = co.Company)
 WHERE COALESCE(st.State, lob.Lob, co.Company) IS NOT NULL
;
```

Comment: i'll give this a shot. thanks so much for the detailed info.

Comment: @Jason - Thank sp_BlitzErik, indiri and Dan Guzman - all I really did was roll their comments into an answer, and add a little sample code.